# Create Virtual Environment The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, django, cmd, operating-system

I want to active the virtualenv `venv` as I am inside the new folder `D:\pythonproject\first_django`

when I run

```
env\Scripts\activate
```

in cmd I get

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

also I installed `venv` , when I run this command

```
pip install virtualenv
```

in cmd I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\sam\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (20.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.2 in c:\users\sam\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in c:\users\sam\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\sam\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<3,>=2 in c:\users\sam\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (2.4.1)
```

can any one tell me what's problem?
I use win11 and python 3.10

Answer (score 4):

Follow the below steps :

To create virtual environment

```
py -m venv env
```

To activate it

```
env\scripts\activate
```

Then proceed with your pip installations in a virtual environment.

Comment: No problem if it solved your problem please mark it as accepted answer so that other can look into it easily.