# Import Error Unused import statement 'import pygame'

Tags: python, pygame, importerror, python-3.10

I'm new to programming and python and, wanted to try pygame but when I put `import pygame`, I get:

```
Unused import statement 'import pygame'
```

I'm using python 3.10.6, what pygame should I install?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use any Python package in the code you need to install it.

To install any package, use the following command:

```
pip install <package name> # for eg: pygame
```

After that, you can use it anywhere in the program.

Also, please be sure that you are in a **proper virtual environment or in a global environment.**

To create a new virtual environment, follow the below solution.

[Create Virtual Environment The system cannot find the path specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71171551/create-virtual-environment-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/71171576#71171576)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where that error message is coming from. Probably your [IDE](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/middleware/what-is-ide), because Python itself won't complain about unused imports.

It sounds like you have typed `import pygame` which makes the pygame module available for you to call (once you install it), but haven't typed any code that *uses* pygame.

For example, I would expect your code to include `pygame.init()` somewhere, because all [pygame clients need to do that](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ImportInit.html) to prepare it.

Once your code actually *uses* pygame, and doesn't just import it, the error should go away.